# Why does nssm.exe cause high WmiPrvSE.exe CPU usage?

Tags: windows, nssm

I am running a java application as a service using nssm.exe.

On Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 I get very high WMI Provider Host CPU usage when using nssm. Without it, I do not see that.

How can I make it so nssm.exe doesn't make WMI Provider Host pound the CPU?

Comment: It's running Java, so naturally it causes high CPU usage. ;)

Comment: I tried a couple other service wrappers... no high WMI event cpu usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's garbage.
I went to WinSW and it's perfect now.